# About the accuracy of NormBound in LSODA

Tags: differential-equations, documentation

As most of us *only* known, LSODA obtains a bound on the dominant eigenvalue by determining the norm of the Jacobian $||J||_p$.

For a comprehensive understand of this powerful stiffness-switch method, I read the [help document](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html#1421611045) and noted that

1. Norm bounds for dense matrices overestimate and the bounds become worse as the dimension increases.
2. Norm bounds can be **tight** for sparse or banded matrices of quite large dimension.

While the word **tight** makes a little bit confusion, to me at least, does it means **accurate** and **precise**. If yes, I really don't understand the two statements. Could anyone explain these in some unambiguous and more explicit forms? Explanation at any level of specificity and complexity are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a mathematica.stackexchange question, no? It's much more math.stackexchange or cs.stackexchange, I'd say (if the latter exists).

Comment: @MB1965 It exists, but it is not for questions like this. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ is better.

Comment: However, this question does seem to be about a specific implementation in Mathematica.